# Conversão de resource (stream) no php trazendo resultados não esperados

Tags: php, postgresql

**Ambientes**

- **Local**

  - *OS:* Linux Mint 19.3;
  - *Banco:* PostgreSQL 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-2.pgdg18.04+1);
  - *PHP:* 7.3.17-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1.
- **Amazon**

  - *OS:* Amazon Linux 2018 V1 - BeanStalk V2.9.3;
  - *Banco (RDS):* PostgreSQL 12.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu;
  - *PHP:* 7.3.15

Tenho uma tabela de queues que possui um campo do tipo `bytea`, ele armazena diversas informações em *json*, ao ser recuperado no PHP ele é identificado como um resource (stream)...

No ambiente local, a conversão utilizando `stream_get_contents`, funciona normalmente... porém no ambiente da AWS (máquina criada através do Beanstalk + Pipeline) não, exemplo:

**Local**

```
// Antes da conversão
var_dump(stream_get_meta_data($r['job']));

// Resultado
array (size=7)
  'timed_out' => boolean false
  'blocked' => boolean true
  'eof' => boolean false
  'stream_type' => string 'MEMORY' (length=6)
  'mode' => string 'w+b' (length=3)
  'unread_bytes' => int 0
  'seekable' => boolean true

// Conversão
$r['job'] = stream_get_contents($r['job']);

// Resultado
var_dump($r['job']);
string(532) '{"class":"common\jobs\EmailJob","from": ........'
```

**AWS**

```
// Antes da conversão
var_dump(stream_get_meta_data($r['job']));

// Resultado
array (size=7)
  'timed_out' => boolean false
  'blocked' => boolean true
  'eof' => boolean false
  'stream_type' => string 'MEMORY' (length=6)
  'mode' => string 'w+b' (length=3)
  'unread_bytes' => int 0
  'seekable' => boolean true

// Conversão
$r['job'] = stream_get_contents($r['job']);

// Resultado
var_dump($r['job']);
string(1077) "x7b22636c617373223a22636f6d6d6f6e5c5c6a6f62735c5c456d61696c4a6f62222c2266726f6d223a7b2272616661656c2e7769746....."
```

O código foi testado localmente por outros desenvolvedores, inclusive em ambiente Windows, e não ocorreu esse problema... O que pode estar causando essa divergência de conversão no servidor?